# React Native - Импорт CheckBox из разных источников в зависимости от платформы

Tags: react-native

Всем привет!
Пишу мобильное и web приложение на React Native, где мне требуется использовать CheckBox. Но получается так, что в web-приложении чекбокс работает, когда я его импортирую из react-native-web:

```
import {CheckBox} from 'react-native-web';
```

А на мобильном устройстве (а именно - на Android) чекбокс работает, когда я его импортирую из @react-native-community/checkbox:

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
```

Один импорт для всех устройств не срабатывает.

Мой вопрос: как я могу указать нужный мне импорт в зависимости от платформы?
Я хотела воспользоваться Platform.select, но тогда возникает ошибка "'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level.". Использовать разные расширения файлов в зависимости от платформы не хочется, поскольку код на данный момент отличается только этим импортом.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {CheckBox as CheckBoxIOS} from 'react-native-web';
import CheckBox as CheckBoxAndroid from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
```

В коде по Platform нужный отображаешь

https://learn.javascript.ru/import-export#eksportirovat-kak

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение и извиняюсь за очень поздний ответ (меня внезапно переключили на другой проект)! Мне не удается использовать переименование для импорта с дефолтным экспортом (в CheckBoxAndroid), но это не столь важно. Проблема в том, что даже с использованием этого решения веб ругается на импорт из @react-native-community/checkbox (Ошибка: "export 'default' (imported as 'CheckBox') was not found in '@react-native-community/checkbox' (possible exports: __esModule)"). Что-то можно с этим сделать?

Comment: @IrinK попробуйте import { CheckBox as CheckBoxAndroid } from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

Comment: Ничего не меняется, только и на Android перестало работать. На веб всё та же ошибка  "export 'CheckBox' (imported as 'CheckBoxAndroid') was not found in '@react-native-community/checkbox' (possible exports: __esModule)"